# Box Plot of Classified Data

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, charts

I have three sets of data which are collected in Jan, Feb and Mar respectively.  I would like to make a box plot to show the monthly variations.  As the data volume is large, I classified the data into different classes (from 0 to 10) first rather than using BoxWhiskerChart directly.  The first column in the following table is the value and 2nd to 4th column are the number of counts from 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc.

Based on these table, is it possible to make a box plot for each month in Mathematica?  or I still need to use BoxWhiskerChart with the unclassified dataset?

Many thanks in advance.

{{"", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"}, {0, 0., 1.1, 6.7}, {1, 20., 80.8,813.}, {2, 846.1, 8833.1, 4681.2}, {3, 5131.5, 15486.1,12068.1}, {4, 229821., 89304.5, 48368.2}, {5, 8784.6, 8846.7,187924.}, {6, 515., 8799.1, 46853.9}, {7, 137.8, 154.8, 4874.1}, {8,0., 666.7, 974.5}, {9, 0., 70.9, 897.9}, {10, 0., 880., 79.1}}

[image]

Comment: The documentation for `BoxWhiskerChart` describes how to create a single chart with multiple datasets.  How did that not work for you?  If as you say you have lots of data, then boxplots are not as informative as nonparametric density estimates (`SmoothKernelDistribution`) or even histograms.  (And if the 2nd to 4th columns are counts, why are not all of those values integers?)

Comment: The data is about number of rain drop.  The sampling was integer at first but then converted to density per volume per unit length, so became real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JimB suggested, using `BoxWhiskerChart` or `Histogram` on original data (or on a random sample of it) is the better approach.

If you ***have to*** use the summary table to create a `BoxWhiskerChart` you can

1. construct `WeightedData` objects using the frequencies and bin
   values,
2. create distributions using `SmoothKernelDistribution` on the
       weighted data objects,
3. create a new sample with large enough sample size from each
   distribution created above,
4. use `BoxWhiskerChart` or `DistributionChart` with the constructed data set.

```
table = {{"", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"}, {0, 0., 1.1, 6.7}, {1, 20., 80.8, 813.},
 {2, 846.1, 8833.1, 4681.2}, {3, 5131.5, 15486.1, 12068.1}, {4, 229821., 89304.5, 48368.2}, 
 {5, 8784.6, 8846.7, 187924.}, {6, 515., 8799.1, 46853.9}, {7, 137.8, 154.8, 4874.1}, 
 {8, 0., 666.7, 974.5}, {9, 0., 70.9, 897.9}, {10, 0., 880., 79.1}};

labels = Rest@table[[1]];
data = Rest@table;
values = data[[All, 1]];
weights = Transpose[data[[All, 2 ;;]]];
weighteddata = WeightedData[values, #] & /@ weights;
data2 = RandomVariate[SmoothKernelDistribution[#], 500] & /@ weighteddata; 

BoxWhiskerChart[data2, ChartStyle -> 97, ChartLabels -> labels]
```

[image]

```
DistributionChart[data2, ChartElementFunction -> "BoxWhisker", ChartLabels -> labels]
```

[image]

```
DistributionChart[weighteddata, ChartElementFunction -> "Density", ChartLabels -> labels]
```

[image]